# Getting ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException without version annotation or OptimisticLocking strategy

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, spring-data

I am getting optimistic locking exception (mentioned below) but strange thing is we haven't specified any of our entities with @version annotation or OptimisticLocking, so just wondering what can cause this exception? We are using JPA, hibernate, spring data & spring. Database is postgresql.

```
System exception occurred while processing request, ERROR_CODE: a18d5739 org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:301)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:485)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not about Optimistic lock. This exception is throwing while deleting/updating a record by Id that does not exists at all. So check that record you are updating/Deleting actually exists in DB.

However, to get a better handle as to what causes the problem you can:

1) Set show_sql as true
2) Set the log levels for Spring and Hibernate to DEBUG

This will help you to understand the issue and fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Then why is throwing this exception and according to javaDocs it's violation of optimistic locking https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException.html

Comment: could be that exists two transactions over the same record. You can check this case here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46989666/3082959
Hope this can help you =)

Answer (score 0):

So the reason you get ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException is that the update statement is using the version column as part of the predicate.

When Hibernate fetches the record that you are going it update it is also pulling back the version column.

```
select id, value, version from my_table where id = 1;
```

which lets say returns back (1, 'cur_val', 6)

You then update 'cur_val' to 'new_val'.

On commit of the transaction the update statement will be link so.

```
update my_table set value='new_val', version=7 where id = 1 and version=6;
```

So if another update has already been made between the time you queried for the object and the transaction

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. What I found is below,
I put @Version on newly added column to the table which was already exists and legacy data was not available in that column. This might be helpful for other who are facing the same issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).