# I am getting "org.hibernate.StaleStateException : Batch update returned unexpected row count from update" in read operation

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I am getting "**org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException**" and "org.hibernate.StaleStateException" exception.

My code is simple and i am running my code in transaction (@Transactional of spring). First it get user entity from database . Second time when i am going to get the same user entity, Exception is coming mentioned above.

Please find my code below- :

```
final UserEntity user = userRepo.findByUserRefId(userDataPayload.getUserDetails().getUserRefId());
```

when i am doing this second time Exception is coming

Comment: You are possibly running long transactions and your entity has versioning, too. Check scope of your `@Transactional` method and also check if entity is modified before you are reading second time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate - Batch update returned unexpected row count from update: 0 actual row count: 0 expected: 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743130/hibernate-batch-update-returned-unexpected-row-count-from-update-0-actual-row)