# Batch update returned unexpected row count from update JAVA

Tags: java, spring-boot

When i try to add user throws next exception:

```
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed: update final_project_user.users set date_of_create=?, date_of_update=?, mail=?, nick=?, password=?, status=? where uuid=? and date_of_update=?
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3571) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3438) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3852) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:201) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:489) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3290) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2425) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at com.example.user_service.service.UserAccountService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9be5cd58.userRegistration(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.user_service.controllers.UserAccountController.userReg(UserAccountController.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at com.example.user_service.controllers.filter.JwtFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtFilter.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1787) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

This is my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users",schema = "final_project_user")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 84661L;

    private UUID uuid;

    private LocalDateTime dtCreate;

    private LocalDateTime dtUpdate;

    private String mail;

    private String nick;

    private UserStatus status;

    private Set<UserRole> role;

    private String password;

    @Id
    @ReadOnlyProperty
    public UUID getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(UUID uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    @ReadOnlyProperty
    @Column(name = "date_of_create")
    public LocalDateTime getDtCreate() {
        return dtCreate;
    }

    public void setDtCreate(LocalDateTime dtCreate) {
        this.dtCreate = dtCreate;
    }

    @ReadOnlyProperty
    @Version
    @Column(name = "date_of_update")
    public LocalDateTime getDtUpdate() {
        return dtUpdate;
    }

    public void setDtUpdate(LocalDateTime dtUpdate) {
        this.dtUpdate = dtUpdate;
    }

    @Column(unique = true)
    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public String getNick() {
        return nick;
    }

    public void setNick(String nick) {
        this.nick = nick;
    }

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public UserStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(UserStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = UserRole.class,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "uuid"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public Set<UserRole> getRole() {
        return role;
    }

public void setRole(Set<UserRole> role) {
    this.role = role;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

This is my service:

```
@Service
    public class UserAccountService implements IService, UserDetailsService {
    
        private final UserRepository userRepository;
    
        private final IUsersMapper usersMapper;
    
        private final PasswordEncoder encoder;
    
        private final UserHolder holder;
    
        private final IAccountUserMapper accountMapper;
    
        @Autowired
        public UserAccountService(UserRepository userRepository, IUsersMapper usersMapper,
                                  PasswordEncoder encoder, UserHolder holder, IAccountUserMapper accountMapper) {
            this.userRepository = userRepository;
            this.usersMapper = usersMapper;
            this.encoder = encoder;
            this.holder = holder;
            this.accountMapper = accountMapper;
        }
    
        @Override
        public UserRegistration userRegistration(UserRegistration userReg) {
    
            UserEntity userEntity = accountMapper.fromDTOtoEntity(userReg);
    
            userEntity.setPassword(encoder.encode(userEntity.getPassword()));
    
            userRepository.save(userEntity);
    
            return userReg;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String userLogin(UserLogin userLog) {
    
            UserDetails userDetails = loadUserByUsername(userLog.getLogin());
    
            if (!encoder.matches(userLog.getPassword(),userDetails.getPassword())) {
                throw new PasswordNotCorrectException(userLog.getPassword());
            }
    
            return JwtTokenUtil.generateAccessToken(userDetails);
        }
    
        @Override
        public UserToRead userInfo() {
    
            UserDetails user = holder.getUser();
    
            return accountMapper.fromEntityToDTO(((UserImpDetails) user).getUser());
        }
    
        @Override
        public UserToAdd addNewUser(UserToAdd userAdd) {
    
            UserEntity userEntity = usersMapper.fromDTOtoEntity(userAdd);
    
            userEntity.setPassword(encoder.encode(userEntity.getPassword()));
    
            userRepository.save(userEntity);
    
            userAdd.setPassword(userEntity.getPassword());
    
            return userAdd;
        }
    
        @Override
        public UsersPage<UserToRead> getUserPage(Integer size, Integer page) {
    
            Page<UserEntity> userPage = userRepository.findAll(
                    PageRequest.of(--page, size, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "nick")));
    
            return usersMapper.fromEntityPageToDTOPage(userPage);
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public UserToRead readUserInfo(String uuid) {
    
            UserEntity userEntityFound = findUserById(UUID.fromString(uuid));
    
            return usersMapper.fromEntityToDTO(userEntityFound);
        }
    
        @Override
        public UserToAdd updateUserInfo(UserToAdd userUpd, String uuid, LocalDateTime dtUpdate) {
    
            UserEntity user = usersMapper.updateUserEntity(findUserById(UUID.fromString(uuid)), userUpd);
    
            user.setPassword(encoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    
            if (dtUpdate.equals(user.getDtUpdate())) {
                userRepository.save(user);
            } else {
                throw new OptimisticLockException("User with uuid " + uuid + " updated early. Try again.");
            }
    
            userUpd.setPassword(user.getPassword());
    
            return userUpd;
        }
    
        private UserEntity findUserById(UUID uuid) {
            return userRepository.findById(uuid).orElseThrow(()-> new UserNotFoundException(uuid));
        }
    
        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    
            UserEntity user = userRepository.findUserEntityByMail(username).orElseThrow(
                    () -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User with such mail not found"));
    
            return new UserImpDetails(user);
        }
    }
```

Mapper for reg user:

```
public class UserAccountMapper implements IAccountUserMapper {

    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public UserAccountMapper(ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public UserEntity fromDTOtoEntity(UserRegistration userDTO) {

        UserEntity userEntity = modelMapper.map(userDTO,UserEntity.class);

        setDefaultFields(userEntity);

        return userEntity;
    }

    @Override
    public UserToRead fromEntityToDTO(UserEntity userEntity) {
        return modelMapper.map(userEntity, UserToRead.class);
    }

    private void setDefaultFields(UserEntity userEntity) {
        userEntity.setUuid(UUID.randomUUID());
        userEntity.setDtCreate(LocalDateTime.now());
        userEntity.setDtUpdate(userEntity.getDtCreate());
        userEntity.setRole(Set.of(UserRole.USER));
        userEntity.setStatus(UserStatus.WAITING_ACTIVATION);
    }
}
```

I found some strange things like:
when i dont set field ROLE in mapper i dont recive this excep;
i create my DB with dates, and when i have it's with nanos in db, i dont recive exception,
but when i trim it in DB to millis, it's start to throw it;
it start throw after commitTransactionAfterReturning, so it's a problem with transaction, but i dont understand what a problem, read a lot of articles, but not one help me.

Comment: For the records: If using Spring Boot 2.7 with H2, you may run into an Hibernate bug also resulting into a StaleStateException, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73635372/2011748

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throwing an error because i manually set field dtUpdate which is annotated version. After i delete setDtUpdate in mapper, it's work okay.